# How to write/read data to a file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating an application in C# Universal Windows and I would like to know how would would I go about writing data to a file so that I can read from it later. I was thinking of making a class `System.Serializable` and then write objects of that class as files to the user's device so then I can read those files back as objects again but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It has all the abilities you need - open a file, read its contents, edit, save or delete.
From MSDN:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        // Create a file to write to.
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Hello");
            sw.WriteLine("And");
            sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
        }
    }

    // Open the file to read from.
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        string s = "";
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer. I am a aware of the File class and IO class as I have a background in Unity. However I don't know the proper method to do it using the Windows 10 API. Could you possibly give a small code example please.

Comment: Done @JoshBaz :)

Comment: @JoshBaz `File` isn't related to Unity or Windows 10.  It's simply part of .Net Framework.

Comment: @Amy nah I wasn't implying that. What I meant is I got to learn about these classes by coding in Unity but I just want to know how to do the same think in this platform.

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET framework, there is a namespace called System.IO.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath);
```

You can use the StreamWriter from the System.IO namespace to write to a file. The constructor simply takes in a string variable to the path of the file you want to write to. Then you can use a StreamReader (like so):

```
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filepath);
```

to read the file back again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Property1{ get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item = new MyClass();
        item.Property1 = "value1";
        item.Property2 = "value2";

        // write to file
        FileStream s = new FileStream("myfile.bin", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
        f.Serialize(s,item);
        s.Close();

        // read from file
        FileStream s2 = new FileStream("myfile.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Read);

        MyClass item2 = (MyClass)f.Deserialize(s2);
    }
}
```